# How to write a stored procedure for both INSERT and UPDATE in one script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure that can do `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. However, I am having a hard time to combine them into one script.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prod1
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t1 ([Account], [Chart Code], [Active])
        SELECT col1 AS [Account], col2 AS [Chart Code], col3 AS [Active]
        FROM t1 
        LEFT JOIN t2 prod ON t1.Account = t2.Account
        WHERE t2.Account is NULL
END;
```

Here is my update script

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[Chart Code] = CAST(t2.col2 as nvarchar(6)),
    t1.[Active] = CAST(t2.col3 as tinyint)
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.Account = t2.col1
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: What do you gain by squishing these together into one?? I would just create **two** separate stored procedures - one for the `INSERT`, the other for the `UPDATE` - makes a lot more sense in my opinion ....

Comment: what's actually stopping you from doing so? What did you try? What went wrong, exactly? There's no attempt shown here. Also, as marc_s says, what's the purpose of doing so? There's no obvious value in it.

Comment: maybe you are asking about MERGE?

Comment: You're **inserting** into a table `t1`, while you're **updating** a table `dim` - are those identical (just bad naming in the sample code) ??

Comment: The post has been edited.  I am sorry for the typo.  I have to perform both operations in a single stored procedure as required.  I can't use MERGE.  I already have both INSERT and UPDATE scripts ready to go.  I just don't know how to put them together in a single stored procedure.  Thanks

Comment: A stored procedure can contain multiple statements between the `BEGIN` and `END` keywords... have you tried simply adding the update statement after the insert statement?

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to test this due to lack of source data and expected results, however converting what you supplied, I believe the below is your desired Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prod1
AS
BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 prod ON t1.Account = t2.Account WHERE t2.Account is NULL)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO t1 ([Account], [Chart Code], [Active])
                SELECT col1 AS [Account], col2 AS [Chart Code], col3 AS [Active]
                FROM t1 
                LEFT JOIN t2 prod ON t1.Account = t2.Account
                WHERE t2.Account is NULL
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE t1
            SET t1.[Chart Code] = CAST(t2.col2 as nvarchar(6)),
                t1.[Active] = CAST(t2.col3 as tinyint)
            FROM t1 
            INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.Account = t2.col1
        END

END;
```